# VC++ to separate Date and Time

Tags: visual-c++

I tried to use DateTime::Now to show system date time.

[image]

I wish to separate them into `<date  hour  mins  secs>`, so that I can use the hour and mins to perform some calculation.

Can it be done?

Comment: More info please. What language and libraries are you using? Some source code would be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DateTime` structure returned by `DateTime::Now` is documented on [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx).

There are plenty of properties that allow you to access the components of the date. For example

```
DateTime pNow = DateTime::Now;
int nDay = pNow.Day;
int nYear = pNow.Year;
int nHour = pNow.Hour;
int nMinute = pNow.Minute;

// etc. etc.
```

Comment: Thanks ! i have just started to learn VC++ through youtube yesterday..thus i have very limited idea on component...swt..